# Using pandas to filter data frame for the most popular factors

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data set with factors in pandas and I have factors 'A' through 'Z' and suppose factors 'A', 'B', and 'C' have 30 observations while the rest only have 5.  There are other columns in this data frame but I am only concerned about this column of factors (let's call it `factor1`).

What operation do I use with pandas to filter this data frame so that the only rows in the data frame are those whose factors that have more than 20 observations? What operation do I use if I want the top 3 most popular factors for `factor1` in the data frame?

EDIT:
Here's a limited set of code

```
data = {'factor1':['A','A','A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C','C', 'D'], 'factor2':['apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','apple','orange','orange','orange'], 'response':range(9)}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
```

How do I filter `df` so that `factor1` has the top 3 most popular factors or factors that have a frequency greater than 5 (or n or whatever really)

Comment: Could you post an example data? The column of factors has only one value or a list of factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for **the top 3 most popular factors**:

```
N = 3
handy = df.groupby('factor1')['factor1'].count()
handy.sort('factor1',ascending=False)
topNFactors = handy.head(N)
print topNFactors

dataOfTopNFactors = df[df['factor1'].map(lambda x: x in topNFactors)]
print dataOfTopNFactors
```

Or try this for **the factors with frequency at least 2**:

```
M = 2
handy = df.groupby('factor1')['factor1'].count()
minimumValueMFactors = handy[handy>=M]
dataOfMinimumValueMFactors = df[df['factor1'].isin(minimumValueMFactors.index)]
print dataOfMinimumValueMFactors
```